# Error when compiling excel formula with pycel

Tags: pycel

I have a spreadsheet with lots of range calculations (Sumifs).

This is the Excel formula:

```
=IF($Q13=0,0,IF(OR($D13>X$7,X$11<IF($D13=$X$3,$AI$2,$U12)),0,MAX(0,MIN($T13,$Q13-SUM($W13:W13),$S13-IF($D13>=$X$3,SUMIF($D$12:$D12,">="&$X$3,X$12:X12),SUMIF($D$12:$D12,"<"&$X$3,X$12:X12))))))
```

When Pycel tries to interpret the range calculation I get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Traceback error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 923, in eval_func
    excel_formula.compiled_lambda())
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 948, in <lambda>
    ### Traceback will show this line if not loaded from a text file
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 782, in _evaluate_range
    data = tuple(
           ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 783, in <genexpr>
    tuple(self._evaluate(addr.address) for addr in row)
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 783, in <genexpr>
    tuple(self._evaluate(addr.address) for addr in row)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 809, in _evaluate
    value = self.eval(cell)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 172, in _eval
    return eval_ctx(
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 934, in eval_func
    error_logger('error', f"{address}{excel_formula.python_code}",
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 877, in error_logger
    raise exc(error_msg)
pycel.excelformula.FormulaEvalError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 923, in eval_func
    excel_formula.compiled_lambda())
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excelformula.py", line 948, in <lambda>
    ### Traceback will show this line if not loaded from a text file

  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excellib.py", line 333, in sumif
    return sumifs(sum_range, rng, criteria)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jtown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pycel\excellib.py", line 348, in sumifs
    return sum(_numerics(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Eval: BS4 Schedule!X14: if_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!Q14") == 0, 0, if_(or_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!D14") > _C_("BS4 Schedule!X7"), _C_("BS4 Schedule!X11") < if_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!D14") == _C_("BS4 Schedule!X3"), _C_("BS4 Schedule!AI2"), _C_("BS4 Schedule!U13"))), 0, max_(0, min_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!T14"), _C_("BS4 Schedule!Q14") - sum_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!W14")), _C_("BS4 Schedule!S14") - if_(_C_("BS4 Schedule!D14") >= _C_("BS4 Schedule!X3"), sumif(_R_("BS4 Schedule!D12:D13"), ">=" & _C_("BS4 Schedule!X3"), _R_("BS4 Schedule!X12:X13")), sumif(_R_("BS4 Schedule!D12:D13"), "<" & _C_("BS4 Schedule!X3"), _R_("BS4 Schedule!X12:X13")))))))
Eval: BS4 Schedule!X9: sum_(_R_("BS4 Schedule!X13:X47"))
Eval: BS4 Schedule!X249: _C_("BS4 Schedule!X9")
Eval: BS4 Schedule!W250: sumproduct(_R_("BS4 Schedule!X249:EB249"), _R_("BS4 Schedule!X250:EB250"))
Eval: Sheet1!D1: _C_("BS4 Schedule!W250")
```

Has anyone encountered this error before and managed to work around it?

Comment: Please add more information to your question: the contents and formulas in your Excel sheet, the Python code you use, what you expect the output to be, what you actually get. See https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel/issues/86 for a good example of how to describe a problem, if you follow the same structure then it will be much easier to answer your question here. Note that that issue is also about `SUMIF` in Pycel but it looks like it is otherwise unrelated to your current problem.

Comment: I have updated the main post with the Excel formula and the traceback error.